# Ruby on Rails 3: Associating extra data with a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Pretty much a total beginner to Ruby/Rails.

I have a Video with many Sections:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@sections=@video.sections;
```

I want to associate a colour attribute with each Section, but the colour is calculated in the controller, rather than stored in the database.

So far I have been simply creating a `@colours` array in my controller where the index matched up with the index of the section

```
hues = [41, 6, 189, 117, 279]
saturation = 100;
brightness = 45;

@colours = [];
@sections.each { @colours.push Color::HSL.new(hues[j%hues.length], saturation, brightness) }
```

so that `@sections[i]` corresponds to `@colours[i]`.

This works fine, but doesn't seem like the best approach. I would like to extend my Sections model so that it has a 'colour' attribute, so that I could access it by doing `@sections[i].colour`

I tried putting this in models/sectiondata.rb :

```
class SectionData
  extend Section
  attr_accessor :colour
end
```

but when I try to do `SectionData.new` in my Controller I get an error saying it can't find the class. I also don't know how I would get the original `@section` to be part of the new SectionData class.

What is the best way to approach this problem? Any tips on my coding style would also be appreciated, Ruby is a big step away from what I'm used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I tried putting them as attr_accessors in the `Section` model, don't do that. Bad coder! They will not show up if ActiveRecord queries the database again for that page load, even if the query is cached. If you need the ActiveRecord methods you can use ActiveModel

Instead, I created a class for the attribute accessors:

**sectiondata.rb:**

```
class SectionData
    attr_accessor :left, :width, :timeOffset, :colour, :borderColour
end
```

Then you can work with them using an object which maps a Section object to SectionData:

**xxx_controller.rb**

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@sections=@video.sections

require 'sectiondata.rb'
@sectionDatas=Hash.new

@sections.each do |i|
  sd=SectionData.new

  # set whatever attributes here, e.g.
  sd.left= total/multiplier

  @sectionDatas[i]=sd
end
```

Then, given a Section object called 'section', you could access it using `@sectionDatas[section]`, and this will work for any database queries that occur in the page of

Answer (score 1):

I think its a better idea to implement [hashes](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) in this situation instead of having two arrays corresponding to each other. 
For example,

```
result_hash = {sports_section => 'blue'}
```

Comment: I had that for some data (there's a lot more than just colours), but I'm curious about how to do it with classes now.

Comment: If you need a 'color' attribute, why not add a database column for your Section model? I don't see a need to extend your Section model and define custom attributes.